# single-row subquery returns more than one row .what should i do in such case

Tags: oracle11g

```
UPDATE STG_ABS_DSD_RECEIPTS_PI_WRK1 A
SET
(
    RECEIPT_HEADER_KEY,
    ORIG_ACNTNG_EFF_DATE,
    GL_DEPT_ID,
    RECEIPT_DATE,
    RECEIPT_TIME,
    TOTAL_INVOICE_COST_HDR,
    SUM_EXTENDED_COST_AMT
) =
(SELECT
    HDR_RECEIPT_HEADER_KEY,
    HDR_ORIG_ACNTNG_EFF_DATE,
    HDR_GL_DEPT_ID,
    HDR_RECEIPT_DATE,
    HDR_RECEIPT_TIME,
    HDR_SUM_TOTAL_INVOICE_COST,
    PIEDW_EXTENDED_COST_AMT
FROM
    STG_ABS_DSD_RECEIPTS_PI_WRK4 B
WHERE
    A.SUPPLIER_KEY = B.PIEDW_SUPPLIER_KEY
AND
    A.STORE_KEY = B.PIEDW_STORE_KEY
AND
    RTRIM(LTRIM(A.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NBR,0)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(B.PIEDW_SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NBR,0))
AND
    TO_DATE(A.PIEDW_INV_TRAN_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') = B.PIEDW_INVOICE_DATE
AND
    B.HDR_FOUND_FLAG IN ('N', 'MY'))
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM STG_ABS_DSD_RECEIPTS_PI_WRK4 B
     WHERE
         A.SUPPLIER_KEY = B.PIEDW_SUPPLIER_KEY
     AND
         A.STORE_KEY = B.PIEDW_STORE_KEY
     AND
         RTRIM(LTRIM(A.SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NBR,0)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(B.PIEDW_SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NBR,0))
     AND
         TO_DATE(A.PIEDW_INV_TRAN_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') = B.PIEDW_INVOICE_DATE
     AND
         B.HDR_FOUND_FLAG IN ('N', 'MY'));
```

Comment: Check your select and look where you made mistake. Without data it is very hard to find mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the subquery only returns the row that you want by providing the correct joins from the table you are updating, or if you just want one row out of many that might be returned then use "WHERE ROWNUM = 1" (or a LIMIT clause in other RDBMSs or Oracle 12c)